# Process.GetProcesses and IsWow64Process does not return all the running processes

Tags: c#, import, cpu-architecture, windows-process

Im using this simple code to list all the running processes and their architecture (`32bit` or `64bit`) on console, And it works nearly accurate but the number of processes in result is not even half of what i see in *WindowsTaskManager* or *[ProcessHacker](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker)*. Most of my running processes are not included in the returning result. And it almost returns just the system processes. Some times i get "`Win32Exception`" or "Access Denied" (maybe because some processes are protected)  and sometimes without Exception:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            try
            {
                if (p.IsWin64Emulator())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName + " x86 " + p.MainModule.FileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.ProcessName + " x64 " + p.MainModule.FileName);
                }
            }
            catch (Win32Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.NativeErrorCode != 0x00000005)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static bool IsWin64Emulator(this Process process)
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5 || Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5 && Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor >= 1)
        {
            return NativeMethods.IsWow64Process(process.Handle, out var retVal) && retVal;
        }

        return false;
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr process, [Out] out bool wow64Process);
}
```

So here is my question: Why this code does not show me all the processes in result? And how to solve this problem?

Example of What is included:

```
conhost x64
OpenWith x64
LockApp x64
ShellExperienceHost x64
SearchUI x64
...
```

Example of what is not included:

```
CSh_Test x64 --> Current Running Sotfware in debug mode
explorer x64
ccSvcHst x86 --> Symantec AV
devenv x86   --> Visual Studio
XYplorer x86 --> File manager
```

Answer (score 1):

GetProcesses() gives you the running processes, but not the underlying services which are also shown in WindowsTaskManager.  Maybe that's the difference you are experiencing?

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses?view=netframework-4.7.2

If not, please give some more information about what is shown and what is not.

Comment: How can i get the underlying services? I have provided some examples too. Also when i get `p.MainModule.FileName` the number of results is different from when i am not getting `p.MainModule.FileName`.